# How to stop <embed> audio with jquery

Tags: jquery

I've tried using this:

```
var bangsat = $("#changeaudio");
bangsat[0].stop();
```

Html:

```
<embed id="changeaudio" src="anysong.wav"></embed>
```

My question is, how to stop the audio file inside embed tag using jquery

Comment: Your title says "with jQuery" but your question says "using JavaScript" (which I take to mean "without using jQuery") - which is it?

Comment: I've re edit the question

Comment: You're missing an "=" for `id`, and embed is a self-closing tag in HTML5 onwards (which is the only version where it's officially valid).

Comment: I've reedit the question. Sorry for mistake

Answer (score 0):

`VM855:49 Uncaught TypeError: bangsat[0].stop is not a function` Because it works only in IE.

You should use `audio` and `video` tags instead of `embed`. Refer: [Using HTML5 audio and video](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

You can use something like that:

```
<audio id="changeaudio" src="http://www.tagindex.net/html/embed/image/example2.wav"
  preload="auto" autoplay controls></audio>

$(document).ready(function() {
  // pause after 2 seconds.
  setTimeout(function() {
    var audio = $("#changeaudio")
    audio[0].pause()
  }, 2000)
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hisener/vw2g73yL/)

Make sure you use `http` instead of `https`. Because audio source is `http`.

Answer (score 0):

`<embed />` doesn't really have API for manipulating audio or video - you're at the mercy of whatever plugins the user has installed in their browser.

What you should be using is the `<audio>` element. Here's an example:

```js
$(function() {
  var bangsat = $("#changeaudio");

  $('#start').on('click', function(e) {
    bangsat.trigger('play');
  })

  $('#stop').on('click', function(e) {
    bangsat.trigger('pause');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<blockquote>
30 second sample from "Another Day in Paradise", <cite>by Phil Collins, from the Collins album, "...But Seriously".</cite>
</blockquote>
<p>
<audio id="changeaudio" controls>
  <source type="audio/ogg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9f/Sample_of_%22Another_Day_in_Paradise%22.ogg">
</audio>
</p>
<p>
<button type="button" id="start">
  Start
</button>
<button type="button" id="stop">
  Stop
</button>
</p>
```

Assuming you go that route, you should provide more than one audio format. I would suggest reading the MDN article [*Video and audio content*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Video_and_audio_content) for the how's and why's of doing so, but in a nutshell, you should have both an MP4 file and a WebM file if you want good coverage of modern browsers.